# Weaving N iterable arguments of equal length

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

In the snippet below I have a segment of code that is currently acting as I want it to:

```
def weave_iterable(*iters):
    return ''.join('{}'.format('{}'*len(chars)).format(*chars) for chars in zip(*iters))

>>> string1 = 'aeim'
>>> string2 = 'bfjn'
>>> string3 = 'cgko'
>>> string4 = 'dhlp'
>>> string5 = '----'
>>> iterable_args = (string1, string2, string3, string4, string5)
>>> weave_iterable(*iterable_args)
'abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop-'
```

However, I am wondering if there is a more efficient and/or more Pythonic way of formatting text that is being returned by my `weave_iterable` function?  Specifically, I'm wondering if there is any way I can avoid using `.format()` twice, due to the unknown number of arguments passed into this function.  I am developing in Python 2.7, but would be happy with an answer in Python 3.x

Comment: does the formatter '-' differ?

Comment: `string5` was purely to demonstrate an example, but thanks for pointing out that I should absolutely have a `sep` argument.  My question specifically refers to the formatting inside the `.join()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) to group corresponding elements of your iterables and [`itertool.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flat the resulting grouped iterables. Then you can directly pass the result to `join` method:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = ['aeim', 'bfjn', 'cgko','dhlp','----']
>>> "".join(chain(*zip(*l)))
>>> 'abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop-'
```

Your function will become

```
>>> def weave_iterable(*iters):
       return "".join(chain(*zip(*iters)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `''.join()` once more to avoid the `{}*len(xx)`.

```
return ''.join(''.join(chars) for chars in zip(*iters))
```

Full program:

```
def weave_iterable(*iters):
    return ''.join(''.join(chars) for chars in zip(*iters))

string1 = 'aeim'
string2 = 'bfjn'
string3 = 'cgko'
string4 = 'dhlp'
string5 = '----'
assert weave_iterable(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5) == 'abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop-'
```

Aside: If you always want hyphen-separated clusters of letters, you can specify that with `'-'.join(...)`, like so:

```
def weave_iterable(*iters):
    return '-'.join(''.join(chars) for chars in zip(*iters))

string1 = 'aeim'
string2 = 'bfjn'
string3 = 'cgko'
string4 = 'dhlp'
assert weave_iterable(string1, string2, string3, string4) == 'abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `interleave` the strings and `intersperse` the dash at intervals using the [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) third-party library:

```
import more_itertools as mit


s1 = "aeim"
s2 = "bfjn"
s3 = "cgko"
s4 = "dhlp"

"".join(mit.intersperse("-", mit.interleave(s1, s2, s3, s4), n=4)) + "-"
# 'abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop-'
```